# Extracting a particular text from html tags using Python's BeautifulSoup library

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<TR>
    <TD ALIGN=center>7</TD>
    <TD>CRM</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>TRF</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>500509</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>23/01/2012</TD>
    <TD COLSPAN=3>JEWEL-NANO-M</TD>


    <TD ALIGN=right COLSPAN=2>1,000.00</TD>

    <TD ALIGN=right COLSPAN=2>0.00</TD>

    <TD ALIGN=right>71,700.00</TD>
    <TD>Dr.</TD>
</TR>
```

I want to extract  the value 'CRM' only, but when i use 'TD' tag in beautifulsoup, it extracts all the other text also.

Comment: consider using regex

Comment: You could use a simple CSS selector like `css_soup.select("td:nth-of-type(2)")`

Comment: If you want only the second element you could do something like `rows = soup.findAll('td')[1]`

Comment: Its a stactic html file. Css selector won't work

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil it reads all the td tags, since the file doesn't have separate blocks.

Comment: Then you must read all the TR tags, and for each one find the second TD within the TR